# SSJS Error - Retrieving data from two DataExtensions and want to update the initial DataExtension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

Anybody an idea what is wrong with this script?
It is my first SSJS script in the automation studio but I just get the error message: *An error has occured*.
I got the functions from the documentary.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionLookupOrderedRows.htm

Best regards,
Alex

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.2");
 var leadRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('Search Agent','Lead:Id,Lead:Sa_City','Lead:Id DESC',['Lead:Status','Lead:lead_Source_comment__c'],['Prospect','City Not Covered']);
 if (leadRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
      for(var i=0; i<dataRows.length; i++) {
        var lead_id = leadRows[i]['Lead:Id'];
        var city = leadRows[i]['Lead:SA_City'];
        var apartmentRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('Apartment__c_Salesforce','Id','Id DESC','Id',city);
        var numberOfApartments = apartmentRows.length;
        var numberOfRowsAffected = Platform.Function.UpdateDE('Search Agent',['Lead:Id'],[lead_id],['Online_AND_Verified_AND_Published_ApartmentsInTheCity'],[numberOfApartments]);
      }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: So the middle part looks now like this: .... if (leadRows && leadRows.length > 0) {
      for(var i=0; i < leadRows.length; i++) { ...
Has somebody else an idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is 2 years old, but I think the issue is the first line: 
    Platform.Load("Core","1.2");
There is no 1.2 as far as I'm aware, try with 1.1.

Also, I can never get the LookupOrderedRows to function with the column names in the second column (as stated in the Marketing Cloud documentation). So the following never works:

```
var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('DE','NAme of Column to return', 'OrderCol DESC/ASC', 'Col to match on', 'Match Value');
```

But this does:

```
var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('DE', number of cols to return, 'OrderCol DESC/ASC', 'Col to match on', 'Match Value');
```

This aligns to the AMPscript LookupOrderedRows function

Answer (score -1):

You should modify the if statement and the for, as follows:

```
if (leadRows && leadRows.length > 0) {
      for(var i=0; i<leadRows.length; i++)
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This answer would be better if you were to go into detail about _why_ this resolves the problem. It may be obvious to you, but being explicit and thorough should help OP (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question), and perhaps others with similar problems, learn from their mistake.

Comment: Hey Derek, 
thanks for your response!

Unfortunately, after changing it, the error still remains.